# How to offer multiple filter options when technically constrained to one?

Tags: gui-design, search, filter, faceted-search

**The Scenario**

I have 2 filters - Filter 1 and Filter 2. In Filter 1 users can either select multiple tabs or enter something in textbox and click `Search Tag` button. Doing this will do ajax call and load image in left box.

In Filter 2, users can select something from dropdown and load data or enter something in textbox and hit button `Search city`.

[image]

**The Problem**

I cannot have multiple filters selected as service which i call through ajax will not accept multiple criteria. Basically i need idea to arrange filters and need to also show on screen what has been selected.

How can I best offer multiple filter options when I am technically constrained to one?

Comment: This answer had received votes to close because it had been phrased and tagged as being about implementation. This isn't a problem about html and javascript. I believe it is a legitimate question for this site when phrased as it is now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Use a tabbed container for the filters

A common and acceptable way to separate filter options, is to user tabs (or versions of tabs) This can often be seen on travel websites, where users can search for several different services.

**With this method, it's only possible to submit one set of search criteria at one time.**

[image]

**Put each set of filters in an appropriately named tab.**

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4DQfX.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Ok tab looks ok. But you see there is option to select multiple tags or enter search in textbox. How would user understand this flow in filter1?

Comment: This part of the UI is unclear from your mockup and description. It would be helpful if you could take a little time and create mockup that is more realistic. Are these tags fixed (always the same)? Are there only 4? or more? Right now your explanation is too minimal and your mockup to general to be able to solve this problem.

Comment: My tags are fixed. Only 4. I can select either multiple tags or enter text and search.

Comment: One idea is to have 4 option buttons. 2 in filter1 and 2 in filter2. Option button will be placed beside multiple tags and one beside search tag button. Clicking any of option button will unlock it and then user can either select multtags or search using box. But that doesnt look good. Hope u got my problem now

Comment: Use a line of copy to explain: "Select (multiple) tags, or type and search". Using JS, if any of the tags are selected, the search input gets cleared. If the user clicks to focus the search input field, the tags gets unselected. This way it's not possible to submit a search with both tag and typed input.

Comment: This is good suggestion. Thanks. If any more better then let me know please. I accept answer but would love to know even better solution

Answer (score 1):

One design options you can look into is using a dropdown call-to-action for your search button. So by default you can present the input elements for one type of search, and when the user selects the other search type you present them with the alternate set of input elements.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXQPYd.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution as per my point of view.

See the image below.[image]